# Each directed graph Has 0 crossing edges in Some DFS Run?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, directed-graphs

I found the following claim online:

For each directed graph, There is DFS run such that it contains 0 crossing edges.

Why is this correct at all?

I think I found a counter example, consider a graph with 3 vertices `1,2,3` with the following directed edges:

```
1->2, 1->3, 2->3
```

Comment: Do you mean cross edge instead of crossing edge? Then, if you do BFS with lexicographic order, you get edge $1\leftarrow 2, 2\leftarrow 3$ and edge $1\leftarrow 3$ is a forward edge.

Comment: sorry, swaps the direction of arrows

Comment: @caduk still what you said doesn't prove or counter example... I showed a counter example and asking if it's correct

Comment: I showed that your counter example is incorrect, because there is a DFS with no cross edge (last edge is forward edge, not cross edge).